# Using Google Maps while offline

Tags: google-maps, offline

I like using Google Maps on my laptop to navigate, but not everywhere I have internet access. Is there a way to use Google Maps when offline? I'd want to have the entire map database for my (small) country on a local file in my computer, and then to be able to use it without having to go online. Is that possible?

(I know that if you load Google Maps and browse around the map, then go offline, you can still look and move around the maps in the parts that were already downloaded, so maybe it's possible to use something like this on a bigger scale.)

Comment: I doubt you want the entire database.  I have an iPad application that downloads the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data.  Washington State by itself uses about 5GB at high detail.

Comment: 5GB sounds totally worth it for my needs.

Comment: Right, but you didn't ask for a single state, you asked for the entire map which would be much larger.

Comment: Why do you think that my country is bigger than your state? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of applications that will allow you to browse Google Maps when offline. One of the better-known is [GMapCatcher](http://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/). However, I'm not sure it will allow you to use it for driving directions, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like a great program, and it's in Python too! Awesome!